# Unable to pass variable to downstream pipeline on GitLab CI

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration

For over a week I've been fighting with passing a variables between jobs in multi-project pipeline in GitLab CI and got lots of weird errors. The mechanism looks like very basic and it drives me crazy that such an obvious thing still doesn't work for me, if somebody ran into similar issues - I would appreciate your help!

So what I've been trying to make:
I have two projects on gitlab and I'm trying to link them in a single multi-project pipeline, the jobs schema looks like this:
In project A:

```yaml
variables: BUILD_PATH:""

build:
    script:
        - $BUILD_PATH="some-path" #the important point here that this value sets inside the job, it's not static

bridge:
  variables: 
    PATH: $BUILD_PATH
    RUN_TYPE: test #this value is a static and it passes correctly, no issues here
  trigger:
    project: project-B-path
```

In project B:

```yaml
variables: 
  PATH: ""
  RUN_TYPE: ""

test:
  script: 
    echo "From upstream pipeline dynamic: $PATH"
    echo "From upstream pipeline static: $RUN_TYPE"
    ...
```

When I run it on CI I have the $RUN_TYPE variable correctly passed and empty value in $PATH variable (even though, $BUILD_PATH has the correct value during run of the build job). Tried many approaches - to set the $BUILD_PATH value in before script, to pass environment value (like CI_JOB_ID) to job in project B, to not create this variable at all in project B, etc. Nothing helped, dynamic variable always has empty value.

Then I've tried to save the dynamic var $BUILD_PATH in .env file and to publish it as artefact, so the bridge job could read it from there. I did it like that:

```yaml
build:
    script:
    - some code here
    - echo "BUILD_VERSION=hello" >> vars.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: vars.env
```

When I run it on CI job always fails with errors like :

```
Uploading artifacts...
825vars.env: found 1 matching files and directories   
826WARNING: Failed to load system CertPool: crypto/x509: system root pool is not available on Windows 
827WARNING: Uploading artifacts as "dotenv" to coordinator... failed  id=1877748 responseStatus=500 Internal Server Error status=500 token=some-token-here
828WARNING: Retrying...                                context=artifacts-uploader error=invalid argument
829WARNING: Uploading artifacts as "dotenv" to coordinator... failed  id=1877748 responseStatus=500 Internal Server Error status=500 token=some-token-here
830WARNING: Retrying...                                context=artifacts-uploader error=invalid argument
831WARNING: Uploading artifacts as "dotenv" to coordinator... failed  id=1877748 responseStatus=500 Internal Server Error status=500 token=some-token-here
832FATAL: invalid argument
```

I've also tried uploading .env file without name as I saw somewhere, like

```yaml
 - echo "BUILD_VERSION=hello" >> .env
```

but again no luck, same 500 error. I keep researching this error, but so far - it's with me.

So the point - none of the ways of passing variables to the downstream pipeline in multi-project pipeline worked for me. If anyone met same issues or made it work in a different ways - please help

**UPDATE**:
Resolved this issue in a different way - with cUrl trigger from project A like:

```yaml
    - curl --request POST --form "token=$CI_JOB_TOKEN" --form ref=branchName --form "variables[PATH]=$BUILD_PATH" "https://gitlab/api/v4/projects/projectID/trigger/pipeline"
```

Comment: can you post the full solution including project A and B? I am facing a similar issue as you and I still have some confusion, hence that can help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

I was able to do this by using build.env

upstream project:

```
stages:
    - build
    - deploy

build_job:
    stage: build
    script:     
        - echo var="defined in the job" >> $CI_PROJECT_DIR/build.env
    artifacts:
        reports:
            dotenv: build.env

trigger:
    stage: deploy
    trigger:
        project: path/to/downstream
```

downstream project:

```
downstream:
    script: 
        - echo $var
    needs:
        - project: path/to/upstream
          job: build_job
```

as a bonus, you could also pass along the upstream project's path and branch by adding this block to the `trigger` job:

```
variables:
    UPSTREAM_REF_NAME: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    UPSTREAM_PROJECT_PATH: $CI_PROJECT_PATH
```

and then change the downstream project's `needs` block to

```
needs:
    - project: $UPSTREAM_PROJECT_PATH
      ref: $UPSTREAM_REF_NAME
      job: buildinfo
```

Answer (score 2):

Your downstream project job needs to declare `needs:` on the upstream project job.

upstream project:

```yaml
build_vars:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "BUILD_VERSION=hello" >> build.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: build.env

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  trigger: my/downstream_project
```

downstream project:

```yaml
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo $BUILD_VERSION
  needs:
    - project: my/upstream_project
      job: build_vars
      ref: main
      artifacts: true
```

Comment: I've tried this one too, the downstream job fails right away not even staring with error "This job depends on other jobs with expired/erased artifacts". Upstream job doesn't specify any artefacts expire timeout, looks like this error message not fully correct, but I didn't find the reason yet. Did you have this error using this approach?

Comment: @OksanaVozniuk the person who triggers the upstream job needs appropriate permission in both projects. But I was able to use this exact same test without issues.

Comment: The interesting thing is that I've got wide permissions in both projects, but still researched it, looks like the root cause is somewhere in permissions but a bit deeper. Anyway, it all worked with curl calls, thank you for help

Comment: @sytech Maybe https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/04/22/gitlab-14-10-released/#improved-pipeline-variables-inheritance would be relevant here? (for GitLab 14.10+, Apr. 2022)