# Passing masked CI/CD variables to downstream pipelines

Tags: gitlab-ci

How can I securely pass masked CI/CD variables to gitlab downstream pipelines?

Using build.env as discussed here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74999046/319621

is probably not a secure way - https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#triggerforward cannot be used for masked variables, correct?
Is there a better way?

Comment: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/356946